# How to store the value of button clicked in a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to store the value of a button in a javascript variable once the button is clicked. Following is my button :

nameofService is also a javascript variable

```
var a='<td><button type="button" className="btn btn-info" value="'+nameOfService+'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#remove"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>'
                      +'</button></td></tr>';
```

I want to print the button's value everytime it is clicked and pass on the value further.

For dropdowns I was using the className="dropdown-button btn" because I was using bootstrap,anything like this possible?

Comment: you have used `var nameofService` as value of button, then you already have button value, why do you need to store in variable again?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this one

```js
var nameofService = 'buttonValue';

var a ='<button type="button" id="modalButton" className="btn btn-info" value="' + nameofService + '" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#remove"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>';

document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = a;

var buttonElement = document.getElementById('modalButton');

buttonElement.addEventListener("click", function(){
  console.log(buttonElement.value);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created little stuff for you, it may definitely help to resolve your issue and you may dynamically get and set button value. Please review snippet.

```js
var nameofService;
   var inc = 1;
   var content;
   var nameofService = "Button "+inc;
   function setUpValue(){
    
    var a ='<td><input id="btn" type="button" className="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#remove" value="'+nameofService+'" onClick="getNewValue()"></button></td>';
    document.getElementById("div_").innerHTML = a;
    showNodeText();
   };

   function getNewValue(){
    inc++;
    nameofService = "Button "+inc;    
    document.getElementById("btn").value = nameofService;
    showNodeText();
   };

   function showNodeText(){
    content = document.createTextNode(nameofService+"\n");
    document.getElementById("div1_").appendChild(content);
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">        
        <title>Question 1</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="setUpValue()">
  <div id="div_"></div>
  <div id="div1_"></div>
    </body>
</body>
</html>
```